# Python - For Loop of Itertools Permutations, How to not Create Endless Elif Statments?

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, permutation

I am a python/programming newbie, been at it for a few months. Hopefully this chunk of code is not too big or over-the-top for SO, but I couldn't figure how else to ask the question without complete context. So here goes:

```
import re
import itertools

nouns = ['bacon', 'cheese', 'eggs', 'milk', 'fish', 'houses', 'dog']
CC = ['and', 'or']

def replacer_factory():
    def create_permutations(match):
        group1_string = (match.group(1)[:-1]) # strips trailing whitespace
        # creates list of matched.group() with word 'and' or 'or' removed
        nouns2 = filter(None, re.split(r',\s*', group1_string)) + [match.group(3)] 
        perm_nouns2 = list(itertools.permutations(nouns2))
        CC_match = match.group(2) # this either matches word 'and' or 'or'

        # create list that holds the permutations created in for loop below
        perm_list = []
        for comb in itertools.permutations(nouns2):
            comb_len = len(comb)
            if comb_len == 2:
                perm_list.append(' '.join((comb[0], CC_match, comb[-1])))

            elif comb_len == 3:
                perm_list.append(', '.join((comb[0], comb[1], CC_match, comb[-1])))

            elif comb_len == 4:
                perm_list.append(', '.join((comb[0], comb[1], comb[2], CC_match, comb[-1])))

        # does the match.group contain word 'and' or 'or'
        if (match.group(2)) == "and":
            joined = '*'.join(perm_list)
            strip_comma = joined.replace("and,", "and")
            completed = '|'+strip_comma+'|'
            return completed

        elif (match.group(2)) == "or":
            joined = '*'.join(perm_list)
            strip_comma = joined.replace("or,", "or")
            completed = '|'+strip_comma+'|'
            return completed       

    return create_permutations

def search_and_replace(text):
    # use'nouns' and 'CC' lists to find a noun list phrase
    # e.g 'bacon, eggs, and milk' is 1 example of a match
    noun_patt = r'\b(?:' + '|'.join(nouns) + r')\b'
    CC_patt = r'\b(' + '|'.join(CC) + r')\b' 
    patt = r'((?:{0},? )+){1} ({0})'.format(noun_patt, CC_patt)

    replacer = replacer_factory()
    return re.sub(patt, replacer, text)

def main():
    with open('test_sentence.txt') as input_f:
        read_f = input_f.read()

    with open('output.txt', 'w') as output_f:
        output_f.write(search_and_replace(read_f))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Contents of the 'test_sentence.txt':

```
I am 2 list with 'or': eggs or cheese.
I am 2 list with 'and': milk and eggs.
I am 3 list with 'or': cheese, bacon, and eggs.
I am 3 list with 'and': bacon, milk and cheese.
I am 4 list: milk, bacon, eggs, and cheese.
I am 5 list, I don't match.
I am 3 list with non match noun: cheese, bacon and pie.
```

So, the code all works great, but I have hit a limitation that I can't figure out how to solve. This limitation is contained within the for loop. As it stands I have only created 'if' and 'elif' statements that go only as far as `elif comb == 4:`. I actually want this to become unlimited, moving on to `elif comb == 5:`, `elif comb == 6:`, `elif comb == 7:`. (Well, in practical reality, I would not really need to go beyond `elif comb == 20`, but the point is the same, and I want to allow for that possibility). However, it is not practical to create so many 'elif' statements.

Any ideas about how to tackle this?

Note that the 'test_sentence.txt' and the list of the variable 'noun' here are just samples. My actually 'noun' list is in the 1000's, and I will be working with bigger documents that the text contained within 'test_sentence.txt.

Cheers
Darren

P.S - I struggled to come up with a suitable title for this one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you notice, each of the lines in the `if-elif` statements follows roughly the same structure: you first take every element in the `comb` list except for the last one, add on `CC_match`, then add the last item.

If we write this out as code, we get something like this:

```
head = list(comb[0:-1])
head.append(CC_match)
head.append(comb[-1])
perm_list.append(', '.join(head))
```

Then, inside your `for` loop, you can replace the `if-elif` statements:

```
for comb in itertools.permutations(nouns2):
    head = list(comb[0:-1])
    head.append(CC_match)
    head.append(comb[-1])
    perm_list.append(', '.join(head))
```

You should also consider adding some error checking so that the program doesn't react oddly if the length of the `comb` list is equal to zero or one.

Comment: Thanks Michael, that is a great solution, and soooo much simpler than the route I had headed. I puzzled for a few hours about this before coming here. The only adjustment I had to make was change `head = comb[0:-1]` to `head = list([comb[0:1])`.

Comment: role model for a before/after stackoverflow! py powers.